# How to add a 2.5 percent price increase to my code?

Tags: c

I have a question about an assignment that I am doing. I am writing a program that is supposed to read from the books.txt file, display the book information. Ask the user to enter the percent of price to increase, change the prices of all the books. Write the updated book information back to the same file. Read from the file again, display the updated book information.

I have completed the 1st part of the code, but I cannot figure out how to do the percent of price increase. There is no error with the code, but the problem is that the program doesn't recognize the 2nd part of the code, which is the part that asks for the user to enter a percent of price increase at all. When I compile and run the code, it just returns the 1st part.

Here is the books.txt file:

```
ID: 321
Author: Harry Potter J. K. Rowling
Price: 20.00
 Year: 1997
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
   FILE *file = fopen("books.txt", "r");
   if(file == NULL){
       puts("I'm sorry, but this file does not exist, and cannot be read.");
       exit(1);
   }

   struct NameofBook{
   int id;
   char author[30];
   int year;
   double price;
};
struct NameofBook nb1 = {135, "Twilight Stephenie Myer", 2005, 10.00};
struct NameofBook nb2, nb3, nb4;
strcpy(nb2.author, "Diary of a Wimpy Kid Jeff Kinney");
nb2.id = 246;
nb2.price = 15.00;
nb2.year = 2013;

nb3.id = 432;
strcpy(nb3.author, "The Hunger Games Suzanne Collins");
nb3.price = 25.00;
nb3.year = 2010;


nb4.id = 321;
strcpy(nb4.author, "Harry Potter J.K. Rowling");
nb4.price = 20.00;
nb4.year = 1997;


printf("\nThe 1st book is: \n Id: %d\n Author: %s\n Price: %f\n Year: %d\n \n", nb1.id, nb1.author, nb1.price, nb1.year);
printf("\nThe 2nd book is: \n Id: %d\n Author: %s\n Price: %f\n Year: %d\n \n", nb2.id, nb2.author, nb2.price, nb2.year);
printf("\nThe 3rd book is: \n Id: %d\n Author: %s\n Price: %f\n Year: %d\n \n", nb3.id, nb3.author, nb3.price, nb3.year);
printf("\nThe 4th book is: \n Id: %d\n Author: %s\n Price: %f\n Year: %d\n \n", nb4.id, nb4.author, nb4.price, nb4.year);
fscanf(file,"\n%d\n, %s\n %f\n, %d\n \n" ,nb1.id, nb1.author, nb1.price, nb1.year);
fscanf(file, "\n%d\n, %s\n %f\n, %d\n \n" ,nb2.id, nb2.author, nb2.price, nb2.year);
fscanf(file, "\n%d\n, %s\n, %f\n, %d\n \n" ,nb3.id, nb3.author, nb3.price, nb3.year);
fscanf(file, "\n%d\n, %s\n, %f\n, %d\n \n" ,nb4.id,nb4.author, nb4.price, nb4.year);

printf("Please enter the percent of price increase: \n");
float percentofpriceincrease = 0.025;
struct NameofBook nb1pricenew = {135, "Twilight, Stephanie Myer", 2005, 10.00* percentofpriceincrease};
struct NameofBook nb2pricenew, nb3pricenew, nb4pricenew;
strcpy(nb2pricenew.author, "Diary of a Wimpy Kid Jeff Kinney");
nb2pricenew.id = 246;
nb2pricenew.price = 15.00 * percentofpriceincrease;
nb2pricenew.year = 2013;
nb3pricenew.id = 432;
strcpy(nb3pricenew.author, "The Hunger Games Suzanne Collins");
nb3pricenew.price = 25.00 * percentofpriceincrease;
nb3pricenew.year = 2010;
nb4pricenew.id = 321;
strcpy(nb4pricenew.author, "Harry Potter J.K. Rowling");
nb4pricenew.price = 20.00* percentofpriceincrease;
nb4pricenew.year = 1997;
printf("The price is changed to: %f\n", percentofpriceincrease);
printf("\nThe 1st book's new price is: \n Id: %d\n Author: %s\n Price: %f\n Year: %d\n \n", nb1pricenew.id, nb1pricenew.author, nb1pricenew.price, nb1pricenew.year);
printf("\nThe 2nd book's new price is: \n Id: %d\n Author: %s\n Price: %f\n Year: %d\n \n", nb2pricenew.id, nb2pricenew.author, nb2pricenew.price, nb2pricenew.year);
printf("\nThe 3rd book is: \n Id: %d\n Author: %s\n Price: %f\n Year: %d\n \n", nb3.id, nb3.author, nb3.price, nb3.year);
printf("\nThe 4th book is: \n Id: %d\n Author: %s\n Price: %f\n Year: %d\n \n", nb4.id, nb4.author, nb4.price, nb4.year);
fscanf(file, "nb1.price * percentofpriceincrease", nb1pricenew.price);
fscanf(file, "nb2.price * percentofpriceincrease", nb2pricenew.price);
fscanf(file, "nb3.price * percentofpriceincrease", nb3pricenew.price);
fscanf(file, "nb4.price * percentofpriceincrease", nb4pricenew.price);
```

> UPDATE: Several of the helpful people here have asked me to include the compiler warnings. The problem is that there are no compiler warnings at all. When I run the code, only the 1st part of the code that relates to printing all of the books shows up, but the part that I wrote that pertains to the percentage of price increase does not show up at all, as if I didn't write anything at all.

Comment: So what happens when you run the code? How is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Comment: Vlad Save lots of time: enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: Karl when I run the code it doesnt show the second part of the code at all.

Comment: Thank you for your advice chux. The problem is that there are no compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2):

To raise your price by 2.5% multiply it by 1.025

Answer (score 2):

Lines like this:

```
double percentofpriceincrease = 0.025;
nb2pricenew.price = 15.00 * percentofpriceincrease;
```

calculate how much the price increases by, not the new price. For example:

```
1000 * 0.025 = 25
```

The "new price" number is less than the original price, which should be a red flag. In fact, you should multiply by `1 + the increase`, so e.g.:

```
double  percentofpriceincrease = 0.025;
double  priceMultiplier = 1.0 + percentofpriceincrease;
nb2pricenew.price = 15.00 * priceMultiplier;
```

Comment: Nope, old habit because I wrote C long, long ago when there was sometimes a meaningful performance difference. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

For your case, if you want to "Save" the data (in your text file), please use the following codes

```
fptr=fopen("books.txt","w");

fprintf(fptr,"%s",'New Data');

fclose(fptr);
```

Please amend the fprintf codes to suit your needs.